# How can I set "id" key before saving the document in the mongoengine?

Tags: flask, mongoengine

How can I set my own `_id` in `mongoengine` before saving the document? I want to set to a known id that I can retrieve later. The following is giving me an error. I am using `Flask-MongoEngine`

```
Doc(tile="Hello", id="my_id").save()
```

And the model is defined as follows:

```
class Doc(db.Document):
   title = db.StringField()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
class Doc(db.Document):
    my_id = db.StringField(primary_key=True)
    title = db.StringField()


Doc(title="Hello", my_id="my_id").save()
```